# How to remove previous commits and keep the ones that are my changes?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-rebase

I have a single branch (called `my-working-branch`) that I worked on that have several commits of my changes. When I committed and push my changes to `master`, thus created a pull request for the reviewer to merge, inside the pull request I saw my commits which I want to keep and merge to `master` along with so many other previously committed changes before mine that I've never changed and was committed by a different author. I am using Bitbucket and so some commits are greyed out with an "M" assuming meaning that commit was merged in master already and some without an "M" and isn't greyed out assuming not merged like my commits from `my-working-branch`.

Now that you understand my situation, what I want to do is keep the first four recent commits that I have in the pull request and remove all of the other commits within `my-working-branch` (no one else worked on this branch and made changes to it except me) that seems to be added in a previous date that shows within my pull request I created. I've looked at other stackoverflow questions regarding using the `rebase` command but since from what I understand it's a destructive command and would rewrite history. I would be fine using it if this only affects my local branch and the pull request to reflect that but I wanted to be absolutely sure this is the right direction to go in as in squashing all those previous commits and keep only the first recent four commits that I have changed which should keep changes to just those four commits and the rest not shown in the pull request to then merge to master.

What would be the appropriate action in this situation?

For example: (`d74981d0dcd..041727236cb` first four commits to keep and the rest after that I want to remove from the pull request)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> regarding using the rebase command but since from what I understand it's a destructive command and would rewrite history

That does not matter here, since you are the only one working on that PR branch.

Note: you don't push a PR branch to master, but to the same PR branch on the remote side, and make a PR from that branch, not from master.

Add the remote "upstream" to reference your original repo, and rebase your branch on top of the upstream/master

```
git remote add upstream /url/original/repo
git fetch upstream
git checkout my-working-branch
git rebase upstream/master
git push --force -u origin my-working-branch
```

If you already have a PR from your origin/master branch then do instead

```
git push --force origin my-working-branch:master
```

The rebase option would be:

```
git rebase -i --onto upstream/master 2f1...my-working-branch
```

That will:

- checkout `my-working-branch`,
- reset it to `upstream/master`, and
- replay all commits *after* `2f1` (`2f1` excluded), up to `my-working-branch` HEAD which was `d74`.

Comment: Is it safe to just rebase the unwanted commits instead because I want to keep my changes only and rebase everything else as stated above. I have `my-working-branch` that I would like to rebase and use the force command on it if that’s correct? Would something like `git rebase -i (all previous commits before the first four)` work? And then when I do `git push --force -u origin (my branch name), it’ll only push those first four commits to pull request? Is that correct?

Comment: @TheAmazingKnight you can rebase -i: you will pick only the commits you want. The push --force will rewrite the history of the remote branch with your local history.

Comment: Okay, so it would be `git rebase -i d74981d0dcd..041727236cb` and pick these four commits and confirm. Then `git push --force origin my-working-branch` and that’ll update and overwrite the pull request of this branch removing all previous commits and just have the first four kept changes?

Comment: @TheAmazingKnight No, in your case that would be a rebase onto upstream/master: see my edited answer.

Comment: I’m a little bit confused. So, what you are saying is in my case, that I have a pull request outstanding from `my-working-branch` -> `master`. Doing `git rebase -i --onto upstream/master 2f14727236cb..` will remove all commits previous including 2f1.. except the first four within `my-working-branch` in the pull request that’s outstanding? Also, after the rebase, when I do the `push --force` command, this will just push my first four commits and whatever else was in that pull request would be overwritten and not show in the pull request besides my first four commits intact? Is that correct?

Comment: @TheAmazingKnight Yes that is the idea: force pushing a branch already used by a PR will update that PR.